# Как правильно получить связанные данные с помощью Room

Tags: android, база-данных, kotlin, room

```
@Entity
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Int,
    val petsId: List<String>
)

@Entity
data class Pet(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Int,
    val name: String
)
```

Как из этих двух сущностей User и Pet получить UserWithPets с помощью Room?

```
data class UserWithPets(
    val id: Int,
    val pets: List<Pet>
)
```

Comment: Вы можете посмотреть как реализовано у startAndroid

https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components/27-course/architecture-components/534-urok-10-room-zapros-iz-neskolkih-tablic-relation.html